# GridView is mixing up images

Tags: android, gridview

I have a gridview that starts off empty, then when the user touches a button they add a "exercise" to a list and then I notify the gridview like this

```
Exercise e = new Exercise();
w.addExercise(e);
bwGVA.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

then an empty gridview box appears and if the user touches it a series of images appears and the image they touch becomes the imageview in the gridview. But if they touch the button and add another exercise to the gridview it already by deafult has the same image. It is supposed to be blank

but that is not where I believe my problem is. Below is my getview in the gridview adapter

```
public class BuildWorkoutGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private static ArrayList<Exercise> ExerciseList;
Context c;

public BuildWorkoutGridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Exercise> _list) {
    c = context;
    ExerciseList = _list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ExerciseList.size();
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v;

    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) c
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        v = li.inflate(R.layout.build_exercise_view, null);


    }else{
        v = (View) convertView;
    }

    Exercise e = ExerciseList.get(position);

    TextView Reps = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCustomReps);
    TextView Sets = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCustomSets);
    ImageView ivThumbnail = (ImageView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.ivBuildWorkout_Thumbnail);

    if (e.getSets() != null) {
        Sets.setText(e.getSets().trim());
    }

    if (e.getReps() != null) {
        Reps.setText(e.getReps().trim());
    }

    if (e.getFilepath() != null) {
        System.out.println("filepath:" + e.getFilepath().trim());
        BitmapHelper BH = new BitmapHelper(c);
        BH.loadSingleBitmap("WorkoutImages/" + e.getFilepath().trim(),
                c, ivThumbnail);
        e.setImageStatus(true);
    }

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return v;
}

@Override
public Exercise getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ExerciseList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}



}
```

I think it has something to do with convertview. But I cant figure out what is wrong.

Comment: w.addExercise(e); can you patse this function here

Comment: w is a list of exercises. I am just adding an object to a list. No method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `ViewHolder` Pattern fro smooth scrolling and performance

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

```
static class ViewHolder
{
TextView reps,Sets;
ImageView ivThumbnail;
}
```

Change `getView` to

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) c
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.build_exercise_view, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.Reps = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCustomReps);
        holder.Sets = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCustomSets);
        holder.ivThumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivBuildWorkout_Thumbnail);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }else{
       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Exercise e = ExerciseList.get(position);

    if (e.getSets() != null) {
        holder.Sets.setText(e.getSets().trim());
    }

    if (e.getReps() != null) {
        holder.Reps.setText(e.getReps().trim());
    }

    if (e.getFilepath() != null) {
        System.out.println("filepath:" + e.getFilepath().trim());
        BitmapHelper BH = new BitmapHelper(c);
        BH.loadSingleBitmap("WorkoutImages/" + e.getFilepath().trim(),
                c, holder.ivThumbnail);
        e.setImageStatus(true);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

If you need to update the gridView update the underlying data the populates gridView and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter.

Comment: That made the scroling much smoother, but it didnt fix the main problem. if I add 1 item set and set its picture, then every item I add after that has the same image

Comment: @CamConnor  `BH.loadSingleBitmap("WorkoutImages/" + e.getFilepath().trim(),
                c, holder.ivThumbnail);` could be your problem. the problem is how you set the image to imageview based on the position. gridView recycles views.

Comment: @CamConnor texts displayed properly??

Comment: yes, the problem (which I cant figure out) is that `BH.loadsinglebitmap...` is being called every for every view, and when an exercise is added the `e.filepath` should be null but for some reason it isn't and it is the same filepath as the first exercise

Comment: @CamConnor if text displayed is right. check the `getFilepath()` of Exercise class. the view holder has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Oh, nvm the text is repeating to

Comment: @CamConnor check your Exercise class.

Comment: you wrote `else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
     }` isnt `.getTag()` making it repeat because if its null then it will grab the last view?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43722/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-cam-connor)